# Can prototype properties that aren't writable be shadowed?

Tags: javascript, prototype

While playing around with some pet projects today, I came around a certain peculiarity that I can't quite explain. Here's a log from a node repl:

```
> foo = Object.create({}, { toString: { value: function() { return 'bob' } } })
{}
> bar = Object.create(foo)
{}
> bar.toString()
'bob'
> bar.hasOwnProperty('toString')
false
> bar.toString = function() { return 'nope' }
[Function]
> bar.toString()
'bob'
```

It was my expectation that `bar.toString` would shadow `foo.toString`, however this does not seem to happen. Setting the `toString` property to `writable: true` when creating `foo` makes it work as I'd expected.

Can prototype properties that aren't writable be shadowed?

Comment: clarity: it's useful to note that any property name does the same, "toString2" or "myProp", not just "toString"

Comment: The main issue here is the same as this question: [Creating new objects from frozen parent objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698533/creating-new-objects-from-frozen-parent-objects)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy is right, this question should be closed as a duplicate. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
Object.defineProperty(bar, 'toString', {
    configurable: true, // optional
    writable: true,     // optional
    value: function() { return 'nope'; }
});
```