# Object.defineProperty vs vanilla property

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

Considering the basic scenario of usage, do

```
foo.bar = 'baz';
```

and

```
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
  value: 'baz',
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  writable: true
});
```

behave exactly the same in supported browsers?

Can we fall back to vanilla in pre-ES6 applications just because of favourable syntax or mix both of them without any side effects?

Comment: Your question has a question mark at the end, but it isn't really a question. Can you rephrase the question please?

Comment: When you define a property without using defineProperty, obj.property = 'value' and with defineProperty with all the descriptor object with true values both are same. But when you change the the descriptor object properties like configurable, enumerable or writable both the declaration differ.

Comment: In the vast majority of circumstances, they behave in exactly the same way. However, there is an edge case if the prototype has a different property descriptor: [Creating new objects from frozen parent objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19698533/2074608)

Comment: Thank you all, gents, that's essentially what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they behave the same when

- there is no `bar` property in `foo` (not even an inherited one), so a new one is created, or
- there is a `bar` property that has the `writable` and `configurable` attributes set to `true`

However, if neither of those is given, the two indeed produce slightly different results.

- `defineProperty` does not consider inherited properties and their descriptors
- If the existing (possibly inherited) property is an accessor, the assignment will try to call the setter (and fail if none exists), while `definePropery` will overwrite the property with the data descriptor (or fail if it is an own, non-configurable one)
- If an existing inherited property is a data property, the assignment will fail if `writable` is false, or create a new own property if true, like the `defineProperty` always does
- If an existing own property is a data property, the assignment will fail if `writable` is false, or set the new value if true, while `defineOwnProperty` will fail iff `configurable` is false and overwrite the attributes otherwise.

> Considering the basic scenario of usage

If by "basic usage" you mean no usage of fancy property attributes, then yes they are equivalent. Yet you should just use the simple assignments, for they are easier to read and faster to execute.

> Can we fall back to vanilla in pre-ES6 applications

Notice that full support of `defineProperty` comes with ES5, so unless you need to consider pre-ES5 (old IE) browsers you wouldn't care at all.

Comment: Another requirement for behaving the same is assuming that `Object` is the global one (has not been shadowed) and neither the global `Object` nor its `defineProperty` property have been modified.

Comment: @Oriol: Yeah, sure, I expected `Object.defineProperty` to be the intrinsic method

Comment: Thanks, Bergi, quite comprehensive