# Object.defineProperty() vs Object.prototype.property vs Object.property when to use what?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, prototype, defineproperty

Can somebody give me a good use case of when to use Object.defineProperty(), Object.prototype.property and Object.property.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "`Object.prototype.property`"? There is no such property. Are you asking "*when to use the prototype?*" or "*when to put a property on `Object.prototype`*" or "*What's the difference between putting properties on the prototype and on the constructor?*"?

Comment: You might be looking for [Why is it Object.defineProperty() rather than this.defineProperty()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13239317/1048572) or [Object.defineProperty vs vanilla property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29861269/1048572) regarding `defineProperty`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object.defineProperty or .prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961414/object-defineproperty-or-prototype)

Answer (score 9):

Imagine we have a `person` object with an `age` property with a value of `20`.

> The Object.defineProperty() method defines a new property directly on
>   an object, or modifies an existing property on an object, and returns
>   the object.
>
> `Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)`

**How is this different than the normal assignment operator?**

It gives you more control over creating a property than standard assignment (`person.age = 25`). On top of setting the value, you can specify whether a property can be deleted or edited among other things outlined in more detail here [Object.defineProperty() page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

**A few examples**

To add an name field to this person that cannot be changed with an assignment operator:

`Object.defineProperty(person, "name", {value: "Jim", writable: false})`

or to update the age property and make it editable:

`Object.defineProperty(person, "age", {value: 25, writable: true})` .

Object.prototype.property and Object.property both refer to accessing a property of an object. This is like accessing the `age` property of the `person` object using `person.age` (you can also use `person["age"]`)

Comment: Neither `"Jim"` nor `25` are descriptors.

Comment: So what's the use case? why not simply `person.age = 25`?

Comment: It gives you more control over creating a property than the standard person.age = 25. On top of setting the value, you can specify whether a property can be deleted or edited among other things.

Comment: Yeah, please put that in your answer, that's what the OP wants to know :-)