# Inherited properties prevent setting actual properties?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to inherit default spec properties, such that, when I create specific overwriting values in inheriting specs, I will still have access to (through inheritance) the unmodified spec values:

```js
let default_boltSpec = {
  head_diameter: 2,
  shaft_diameter: 0.8,
};
Object.freeze(default_boltSpec);

let derivedBoltSpec = Object.create(default_boltSpec);
console.log( "derivedBoltSpec:", derivedBoltSpec );

Object.assign(derivedBoltSpec , {
  head_diameter: 1.5,
});
```

The weird thing is that I seemingly am not allowed to "overwrite" inherited values! How can values that are strictly on the prototype chain in any way interfere with what properties I am allowed to put on my object?

EDIT:
This screenshot shows the effect of running the above code snippet in the Firefox web developer console:
[image]

This image reveals that Object.create does not add any properties to the created object. This is in harmony with [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've frozen the object. This will freeze the property values as well.

From the context, I think what you want to use is `seal` instead of `freeze`. For example,

```js
let default_boltSpec = {
  head_diameter: 2,
  shaft_diameter: 0.8,
};
Object.seal(default_boltSpec);

let derivedBoltSpec = Object.create(default_boltSpec);

Object.assign(derivedBoltSpec , {
  head_diameter: 1.5,
});
console.log( derivedBoltSpec)
```

[Here are the docs for seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)

EDIT: You'll have to make the properties writable again. You can do this using Object.defineProperty. But you'd essentially be looping over all the properties and making them writable. For example,

```
Object.defineProperty(derivedBoltSpec 'head_diameter:', { value: 1.5, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true });
```

Comment: I've frozen the *prototype* object ('default_boltSpec'). The object I'm trying to modify is 'derivedBoltSpec' and it has not been frozen.

Comment: But I'm not even trying to change the properties of the prototype object. That's why this is very confusing. The frozen prototype object is never modified after its creation.

Comment: The frozen property propagates with inheritance. With object.create you're basically copying the whole object with all it's properties with their behaviour and it's  prototype(in __proto__) to the new object.

Comment: While your explanation would indeed explain the error message, it relies on a hypothesis which has evidence against it: the hypothesis that any properties at all get copied from the first argument of Object.create onto the created object. I've added this evidence in my question.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19698581/3719089 It was wrong of me to say that properties are copied, I should've clearly mentioned that.